# Why is sf() struggling to run plots quickly on UK datasets?

Tags: r, import, sf

Problem:

When I load in any of the shapefile datasets from [Census data explorer](https://borders.ukdataservice.ac.uk/) plots are brutally slow. I suspect this is an issue specific to running R / RStudio on MacOS.

For replication:

```
require(sf)

download.file("https://borders.ukdataservice.ac.uk/ukborders/easy_download/prebuilt/shape/infuse_dist_lyr_2011.zip", destfile = "data/gis/infuse_dist_lyr_2011.zip")
unzip("infuse_dist_lyr_2011.zip", exdir = "data/gis")
local_authorities <- st_read("data/gis/infuse_dist_lyr_2011.shp")
plot(local_authorities)
```

I'm running MacOS 11.6, R-4.1.2-arm64 and RStudio 2021.09.1+372. I've replicated this problem using R command line and in RStudio, using tmap() and base R graphics. I've also tried using both sf() objects and sp(). Plots take more than 30 minutes, potentially several hours across any of the configurations I've tried.

Following helpful advice from @Spacedman, I've run some subsets with timers on. Code I used:

```
require(sf)
local_authorities <- st_read("data/gis/infuse_dist_lyr_2011.shp")
benchmark("row1" = {
          plot(local_authorities[1,])}, 
benchmark("row2" = {
          plot(local_authorities[2,])}, 
benchmark("row3" = {
          plot(local_authorities[3,])}, 
benchmark("row4" = {
          plot(local_authorities[4,])}, 
replications = 1, columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative", "user.self", "sys.self"))
```

Results are the following:

```
  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
1 row1            1   0.134        1     0.121    0.006
1 row2            1 964.725        1   961.112    2.294
1 row3            1   0.358        1     0.333    0.015
1 row4            1   0.136        1     0.124    0.008
1 row5            1   0.578        1     0.557    0.012
1 row6            1   0.245        1     0.237    0.004
1 row7            1   8.603        1      8.55    0.041
1 row8            1   0.776        1     0.757    0.011
1 row9            1   0.471        1      0.45     0.01
1 row10            1   0.174        1     0.167    0.003
1 row11            1  83.648        1     83.26    0.246
```

Note: I've run replications on 1, 3, 4 and 11 and confirmed that execution time remains relatively stable (e.g. short or long depending) so it does seems to be something in the data here.

A bit more digging into each individual shape in this shapefile seems to indicate that the struggle here relates to the number of parts within each individual MULTIPOLYGON. So row 2 has whereas Shetland, row 244 has 549 parts row 387, has 521 and both lag in similar ways.

I'm a bit out of my depth here in terms of identifying faults within individual polygons, but it seems to be the case that (as suggested some specific shapes are tripping this up, by my testing of the first four, geo_codes: W06000016 and E07000138 (1 and 4) are fine, whereas S12000013 (2) is causing problems.

Happy to try testing if someone can steer me in the right direction.

Comment: I can't replicate this on a fairly old laptop. `plot(local_authorities)` takes a few seconds to plot each of the five maps. Have you tried plotting subsets, eg `plot(local_authorities[1:10,])` and seeing if time scales with size or maybe there's one troubling feature causing a weird loop somewhere...

Comment: @Spacedman thx for this quick reply. What OS is on your laptop? Key feature so far seems to be that stuff runs fine on Windows...

Comment: Good idea re plotting subsets - Ill try this and see if i can recursively identify the issue here...

Comment: Laptop is Dell XPS12 8Gb running Linux, R 4.1.0, sf version 1.0.1.

Comment: I'd be interested to find out if another user on a Mac could run this code without arbitrary delays

Comment: I've just updated above with some extra information based on testing

Comment: Wow. Much weird. Can you edit and show `packageVersion("sf")` and the output from `library(sf)` when it gives the versions of GEOS, GDAL etc? No mac available so I can't help directly sorry :(

Comment: I agree - it's really strange. Here's the outputs you've asked for: packageVersion("sf")
[1] ‘1.0.6’
> library(sf)
Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.2.3, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

Comment: I've confirmed that a workaround to this problem is just to simplify the geographies using a Douglas-Peucker algorithm in QGIS to a high tolerance (100m seems to work). But I do think there might be an underlying bug hiding somewhere in R as others can process this computation so much more quickly.

Comment: Given you've got a reproducible example with that public data set its probably worth filing an issue at https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues - outline the problem and maybe link to this Q from there but copy-paste all your version numbers there as well. You might also want to specify your hardware (RAM, whether Mac is x86 or one of those new ones with a funny CPU...)

Comment: it took `134 s` on my ryzen 7 1700 on pop! os (ubuntu) to plot all 4 fields. `GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.2, PROJ 7.2.1; R 4.1.2`. Have you tried opening it on QGIS?

Comment: Yep. Works fine in QGIS, so that rules out gdal etc

Comment: I've replicated this on iMac intel and Mbp a1

Answer (score 3):

Very helpful answer from a user over on the sf() github repo in response to a [bug report I'd posted](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1909). The problem is caused by poor performance by the default video device on MacOS. Longer conversation about this can be found among [RStudio issues on github](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3866), along with a description of the fix, which is to modify settings in RStudio under `General` > `Graphics` to [AGG](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ragg/versions/1.2.1). Complete shift in performance on my laptop:

```
> benchmark("local_authorities" = {plot(local_authorities)}, replications = 1, columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative", "user.self", "sys.self"))
               test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
1 local_authorities            1   9.017        1     8.073    0.437
>
```

Comment: When using an IDE like RStudio, always test issues in the R terminal to rule out that it is an issue with the IDE. This separates out R and package issues from that of an IDE, which heads off quite a bit of speculation. This is particularly important with RStudio because, it is parsing quite a bit of R before you see results. I have seen this go very wrong with S3 spatial objects and was no fault of R or the package on hand.

Comment: Thanks for this @JeffreyEvans . I did actually test in R command line and replicate there. I gather it also uses the default as is the case with RStudio.

Comment: Jeremy Kidwell, good to know. This ends up being a comment for future readers because, many users are not as savvy as you and do not know the difference between R and RStudio. It is frustrating chasing your tail over a problem that is coming from RStudio and not R. Sometimes an OP does not even mention that they are using RStudio. Now you have me wanting to try ragg under windows.